# Can Jenkins view windows events log file?

Tags: windows, jenkins, event-log

Can Jenkins view windows events log file?

Since I have a site hosted on IIS server, and it will generate some events log. Is there have any solution for me to read windows events log on a jenkins server?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I would *guess* that jenkins has access to any resources on the machine it is running on. But you have to make sure that the corresponding permissions are set accordingly.